# Need help getting Fuego to compile in Xcode - boost version compatibility?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, boost, frameworks

> Semantic issue: 'mutable' cannot be applied to references

The above is only the latest in a series of errors I've received attempting to get the [fuego-iphone](https://github.com/horaceho/iphone-fuego) project to compile. I'm not certain, but it could be related to the way I compiled boost. The project's README recommends using [these instructions](http://semmel.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/boost-c-libraries-with-ios/) for compiling boost into a framework, but I had already done so with the [more recent instructions here](http://www.danielsefton.com/2012/03/building-boost-1-49-with-clang-ios-5-1-and-xcode-4-3/). Could this CLANG error be related to a boost version somehow?

I admit relative ignorance when it comes to C++.

If anyone has any brilliant suggestions for using the fuego library in general with xcode, I have tried quite a few different things, and am pretty much at wit's end. Thanks!

EDIT: Apologies for any ambiguity here, but I'm not asking about mutable references, so much as showing the latest symptom of this issue. The fuego mailing list has [a relevant question](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CALnA2CuN_SDK-RHO8ATsnRADeAqPsoTnPasskkUBv-MVEfQULQ@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=fuego-devel) about using boost 1.48, and checking now, it's clear that I've compiled 1.49, so I'll recompile an earlier version of boost and see if that fixes it somehow.

Comment: Are you asking (what the title implies) about the mutable keyword, or are you asking how to compile and use that library in general?

Comment: My bad. I'll change the title.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this ? I'm getting the same error with clang and boost 1.42.0 on OS X.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never did resolve this, and it essentially killed my project. There are plenty of apps that clearly use Fuego in the store, so it can't be insurmountable, but I've decided my skills are best utilized at the higher-level Objective-C APIs. If I never have to mess with Boost again, it'll be too soon. ;)

Comment: @livingtech: thanks - I've worked around it for now by downgrading from clang to llvm-gcc-4.2.

Comment: Hmmm. Wonder if I ever tried switching compilers. I can't recall. Would be so frustrating if that was my only problem! heh.

Answer (score 4):

The `mutable` modifier means that a field can be changed from within a `const` method. But for reference fields, that doesn't make any sense, because references can never be changed in C++.